# Add Branding Images in salesforce TrailHead

Tags: salesforce

I am working on SalesForce TrailHead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/build_branded_chat/steps/build_branded_chat_build and looking to implement the **Add Branding Images**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got the solution to the above problem. First load all the required static resources.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]